# ASRock C2550d4i FUBAR out of box?

Tags: motherboard

This was my first time using this board. I installed it, and tried to boot only to have it stuck on "System initializing..."
I was, initially, able to access IPMI.

Here's where I messed up.
I tried to do a firmware update. But the HTTP wasn't set up and asked me to upload a file. I canceled the process as I had no file to upload. After that I am completely locked out of IPMI.

I found a USB tool to reset it, but I can't boot to it because the system is stuck on initializing.

I first found out that the RAM I was using (2x4GB Crucial ballsistix DDr3 1600UDIMM 1.5V) was not compatibile. So I got 2x8gb crucial DDR3 1600 ECC UDIMM 1.35V, Crucial's website said this was compatible.

I tried reseating the RAM, no.

Only 1 stick, no

Removed CMOS, no

Tried all the steps here:

http://forums.tweaktown.com/asrock/61395-asrock-rack-e3c226d2i-wont-post-after-bios-bmc-update.html

I cannot get past "system initializing" coming out of the boards VGA, I haven't even gotten a chance to install an OS so IPMItools is out of the question, booting to USB DOS is out of the question. Getting any info from IPMI is useless as I have no access (I can't login but I can access/ping/see the IPMI user interface)

What can I do? Should I get it RMA'd or is there anything I can do?

Comment: @OP have you still got the board? I had similar issues after a FW update and I can try and recall the fix if you like.

Comment: To update: I had it RMA'd, the tech tested it and got back to me and said he couldn't find anything wrong. New board works fine, and has worked since the RMA in October '16.

Comment: Hate to ruin your buzz but its part of the C2xxx series that has a hardware flaw and may die again. Developing story so we have to see what the MTTF is.